# FragmentManager clean up for .addToBackStack

Tags: java, android, navigation, fragmentmanager

Is there anyway I can make this a bit cleaner? I know when query = "" I'm at the main menu and therefore back should close the app.

```
        if (query == "") {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(containerId, fragment, tag)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } else {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(containerId, fragment, tag)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was better for me. Though I appreciate the answer above.

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(containerId, fragment, tag);
     if (query != "") {
         transaction.addToBackStack(null);
     }
     transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can clean-up your fragment from activity one by one, here is the code...

```
   public static void clearBackStack() {
        FragmentManager fm = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
             fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify how would it work with the code I already have

Comment: Yes, getBackStackEntryCount() will give the total number of fragments in stack, and it will removed one by one through popBackStack() method